# URL decode a string but log an error after second exception

Tags: java, error-handling, url

I have a method which does URL decoding on the string value passed along with using `Charset`:

```
  public String decodeValue(String value, Charset charset) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
      try {
        value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        // log error
        return null;
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
```

Now if `URLDecoder.decode` throws `UnsupportedEncodingException` the first time, then I want to run the same `value` against these three lines:

```
value = value.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
value = value.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
```

And if then again `URLDecoder.decode` line throws exception second time, then I will log the error but only second time and return null value otherwise return the value which is decoded so I came up with this:

```
  public String decodeValue(String value, Charset charset) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
      try {
        value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        try {
          value = value.replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25");
          value = value.replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
          value = URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uex) {
          // log error
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
```

I'd like to see if there is any better way to write the above code. As of now, it duplicates the code.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's  move the replacements into a separate `fixErrors` method for readability.

```
String fixErrors(String value) {
    return value
        .replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25")
        .replaceAll("\\+", "%2B");
}
```

Now, my solution would be to write a method that returns the result of `URLDecoder.decode` as an `Optional`. Then, instead of nesting `try/catch` statements, we can just use `Optional::or`. This should look something like

```
public String decodeValue(String value, Charset charset) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        return tryDecode(value, charset)
            .or(() -> tryDecode(fixErrors(value), charset))
            .orElse(null);
    }
    return value;
}

Optional<String> tryDecode(String value, Charset charset) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name()));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this solution precludes logging details of only the second error. To do this effectively, we could add error handling to `tryDecode` by passing it a `Consumer<UnsupportedEncodingException>`. Then we would have:

```
public String decodeValue(String value, Charset charset) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value)) {
        return tryDecode(value, charset, ex -> {})
        .or(() -> tryDecode(fixErrors(value), charset, ex -> {
                // log ex
            }))
        .orElse(null);
    }
    return value;
}

Optional<String> tryDecode(String value, Charset charset,
                   Consumer<UnsupportedEncodingException> exConsumer) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(URLDecoder.decode(value, charset.name()));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        exConsumer.accept(ex);
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this solution meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Check this can be any help.

```
public String decodeValue( String value, Charset charset ) {

    if ( !Strings.isNullOrEmpty( value ) ) {
        try {
            return URLDecoder.decode( value.replaceAll( "%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25" ).replaceAll( "\\+", "%2B" ), charset.name() );
        } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException ex ) {
            // log error
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

or another possible solution I've is

```
public String decodeValue( String value, Charset charset ) {

    if ( !Strings.isNullOrEmpty( value ) ) {
        try {
            return URLDecoder.decode( value, charset.name() );
        } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException ex ) {
            try {
                return URLDecoder.decode( value.replaceAll( "%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25" ).replaceAll( "\\+", "%2B" ), charset.name() );
            } catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException uex ) {
                // log error
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.